# How turn off pluralize table creation for Entity Framework 5?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, pluralize

I am trying to use Entity Framework 5. The first problem was that EF creats tables automatically. I tried to fix it by including 
`dbModelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>()`. The second problem was the error like this

> The model backing the 'CountryContext' context has changed since the
>   database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update
>   the database.

I tried fix it by `dbModelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();` but no sense.
The data access layer the next:

```
Table(Name = "tblCountries")]
public class Country
{
     [Column(Name = "id", IsDbGenerated = true, IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public int Id {get;set;}

    [Column(Name = "name")]
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class CountryContext:DbContext
{
    public CountryContext(string connStr):base(connStr)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Country> TblCountries { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder dbModelBuilder)
    {
        dbModelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        dbModelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
    }
}

    public class CountryDal:BaseDal
{
   public int CheckIsExist(Country country)
    {
        int id = 0;
        using (var context = new CountryContext(ConnectionString))
        {
            var first = context.TblCountries.FirstOrDefault(el => el.Name == country.Name);
            if (first != null)
            {
                id = first.Id;
            }
        }
        return id;
    }
    }
```

Additional info: VS 2012, framework 4.5, entity framework 5.0.0.0
And for EF 4 it works perfect (without OnModelCreating method).

Comment: Complete guess here but does EF still recognize the entity as an Identifier when you imply it as `Id` opposed to using ALL CAPS like so: `ID`

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can write this code in OnModelCreating method:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
```

Comment: using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want EF to create tables and manage consistency between you model and database just use this at the startup of your application:

```
Database.SetInitializer<CountryContext>(null);
```

Comment: This will solve the issue but not the question - However the questioner is asking the wrong question ;)

Answer (score 6):

Using LINQ in EF 6.0:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    var conventions = new List<PluralizingTableNameConvention>().ToArray();
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove(conventions);
}
```

Comment: Weird - you remove an empty array of the target type?

Comment: Just to note *conventions* is not an empty array it contains _PluralizingTableNameConvention_