# Entity Framework Core RC2 table name pluralization

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, pluralize, tablename

Is there a way to do what this code did in EF Core RC 2?

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{    
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}
```

Answer (score 134):

There is no convention for this as of EF RC2 build. This is from EF Core team:

> In past pre-release of EF Core, the table name for an entity was the
>   same as the entity class name. In RC2 we now use the name of the DbSet
>   property. If no DbSet property is defined for the given entity type,
>   then the entity class name is used.

Now if you want to revert back to the RC1 naming conventions for tables, you have 3 ways to go with:

**1. Choosing Singular Names for DbSet Properties:**

One way is to singularize your DbSet property names (which I don't like). Say for example you have a *Book* entity and you want to map to a *Book* table:

```
public DbSet<Book> Book { get; set; }
```

**2. Using ToTable() Fluent API:**

You can of course always use fluent API to override any convention in place and dictate the table name to whatever you want:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Book>().ToTable("Book");
```

**3. Writing a Custom Convention:**

Just because EF Core RC2 does not have a convention for this, it doesn't mean we can't write our own. To do so, first we need to create an extension method on `ModelBuilder` object:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal;

public static class ModelBuilderExtensions 
{
    public static void RemovePluralizingTableNameConvention(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        foreach (IMutableEntityType entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            entity.Relational().TableName = entity.DisplayName();
        }
    }
}
```

And then we simply call it from the *OnModelCreating* method on our *DbContext* object:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.RemovePluralizingTableNameConvention();
}
```

**On Closing:**

I don't like plural table names and I like the last option better than the others and went with that. That said, it's my personal opinion and other developers might find any of these 3 ways more favorable than the others and choose to go with that :)

Comment: Thank you Morteza. I think that for now I'll just set the table name on the entity.

Comment: I also added your way to my answer so that we have them all in one place as a point of reference for other fellow developers. Thanks.

Comment: Morteza - I was actually referring to using the Table attribute on the poco class but I actually like your example #2 even better because that keeps all of the setup in one spot in the context as opposed to sprinkling the attributes on each poco.

Comment: If you're inheriting from IdentityDbContext, make the call to `modelBuilder.RemovePluralizingTableNameConvention();` after `base.OnModelCreating(builder)` otherwise the AspNetUser tables will get mangled.

Comment: @MattMombrea In **EF Core 2.0** calling `modelBuilder.RemovePluralizingTableNameConvention();` after `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);`
does not solve problem when DbContext is inherited from `IdentityDbContext`. ASP Identity table names are still mangled.

Comment: @Tančev Saša I tried to call `modelBuilder.RemovePluralizingTableNameConvention();` before `base.OnModelCreating(builder);` and identity tables have OK names

Comment: IMutableEntityType doesnt have Relational() method, is it changed?

Comment: entity.Relational().TableName = entity.DisplayName(); not work in .net core 3

Comment: You should be able to use entity.SetTableName(entity.DisplayName());

Comment: @MortezaManavi : Calling `modelBuilder.RemovePluralizingTableNameConvention()` causes issues when used in conjunction with `entity.ToView("MyView")`: The entity is then tagged as a table and not as a view anymore.

Comment: The downside to option 3 is that it overrides `EFCore.NamingConventions`. Because of this, I've decided to just use the `TableAttribute` on all my entity classes and be totally explicit about what the name should be. Seems like the only way to get what I want (snake_case, singular).

Comment: Continuing from my previous comment, I decided to stick with option 3 here, but also call [another method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63055998/6236042) to convert the entity.DisplayName() to snake case; `entity.SetTableName(entity.DisplayName().ToSnakeCase());`

Answer (score 69):

For EF Core 3.0 and above, use this to set the `TableName` property (because `entity.Relational()` no longer exist):

```cs
public static class ModelBuilderExtensions 
{
    public static void RemovePluralizingTableNameConvention(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        foreach (IMutableEntityType entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            if (entity.BaseType == null)
            {
                entity.SetTableName(entity.DisplayName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use this method with an inherited entity, you'll get the error `...Only base type entity types can be mapped to a table.`.
To work around this, I used the condition `if (entity.BaseType == null)`. Base classes will return `null` while inherited classes will obviously return the base type.

Comment: @Métoule : Calling `modelBuilder.RemovePluralizingTableNameConvention()` causes issues when used in conjunction with `entity.ToView("MyView")`: The entity is then tagged as a table and not as a view anymore.

Comment: @Métoule please check possible issues and workarouns for EF Core 5 https://stackoverflow.com/a/65585664/1769622

Comment: How about .NET 6? Neither entity.Relational() nor entity.SetTableName() exists in .NET 6.

Comment: @Creative: `entity.SetTableName` exists in EF Core 6.

Comment: Please edit the if clause, throwed an error. Replace instead: if (entity.BaseType == null).

Answer (score 10):

The EF Core version doesn't seem to support `entity.DisplayName`. This is a working alternative:

```
foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    // Skip shadow types
    if (entityType.ClrType == null)
        continue;

    entityType.Relational().TableName = entityType.ClrType.Name;
}
```

Comment: `entity.DisplayName` is an extension method in the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal` namespace (which is actually public, not `internal`).

Answer (score 10):

This is also an option:

```
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

 [Table("Book")]
 public class Book
 {...}
```

although you need to annotate it on each entity

Comment: I found myself wanting to organize via schema, so I was annotating with this tag on every class anyway.  As an Example:   [Table("Book", Schema = "library")]

Answer (score 6):

The EF Core 5 has resolved using a switch "-NoPluralize" while updating the Db Context:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "..conn str.." Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir EntityDbContext -Project DoctorsExpress.Domain -Force -NoPluralize
```

Comment: should be --no-pluralize

Answer (score 5):

In Entity Framework NET core v2 you can choose to **pluralize** or singularize `DbSets` and `Collections` with a hook.

```
public class MyDesignTimeServices : IDesignTimeServices
{
    public void ConfigureDesignTimeServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IPluralizer, MyPluralizer>();
    }
}

public class MyPluralizer : IPluralizer
{
    public string Pluralize(string name)
    {
        return Inflector.Inflector.Pluralize(name) ?? name;
    }

    public string Singularize(string name)
    {
        return Inflector.Inflector.Singularize(name) ?? name;
    }
}
```

See this answer for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47410837/869033

Answer (score 0):

I use this for EF Core 3.1 to preserve `[Table("some_table_name")]` annotation on entity types, although `ConventionAnnotation` is an internal class.

```cs
static class UseEntityTypeNameForTableNameExtension
{
    public static void UseEntityTypeNameForTableName(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            var tableNameAnnotation = (ConventionAnnotation)entity.FindAnnotation(RelationalAnnotationNames.TableName);
#pragma warning disable EF1001
            var configurationSource = tableNameAnnotation.GetConfigurationSource();
#pragma warning restore EF1001
            if (configurationSource != ConfigurationSource.Convention)
            {
                // Set explicitly using Fluent API or has TableAttribute DataAnnotation
                continue;
            }
            var defaultTableName = entity.GetDefaultTableName();
            entity.SetTableName(defaultTableName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I went with adding a virtual

```
public virtual DbSet<TableName> TableName{ get; set; }
public DbSet<TableName> TableNames { get; set; }

TableNames.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Quality username. Low quality answer. You should mention *why* you went with this approach and how it solves the problem in the description.