# How to properly use IPluralizer in IDesignTimeServices

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In my app I use code-first approach and I'm adding entities to DbContext only via `IEntityTypeConfiguration<>`. 
My goal is to achieve pluralized table names i.e. *Models* for *Model*.

After reading [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/services), [article](http://anthonygiretti.com/2018/01/12/entity-framework-core-2-pluralization-and-singularization/), [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281647/entityframework-core-database-first-approach-pluralizing-table-names/47410837#47410837)
my understading would be that my pluralizer should be registered and as `IPluralizer` used during creating migration, however it is not.

Of course I could have implicitly use `DbSet<Model> Models {get;set;}` or use `builder.ToTable("Models");`, but in my generic scenario I'd like to avoid that, especially as I would like some models not to override abstract generic scenario.

Question is, am I doing something wrong, or I misunderstand the way it should behave

**AppDesignService.cs**

```
public class AppDesignService : IDesignTimeServices
{
    public void ConfigureDesignTimeServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        Debugger.Launch();
        services.AddSingleton<IPluralizer, InflectorPluralizer>();
    }
}
```

**MyDbContext.cs**

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser,AppRole,Guid>
{
    public EmsDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(AppDbContext)));
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

    services.AddDbContext<DbContext, AppDbContext>(opt =>
     {
         opt.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sqlOpt =>
         {
             sqlOpt.EnableRetryOnFailure(3);
         });
     });

     // code skipped for brevity
}
```

**Config**

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id {get;set;}
}

public class Model : IEntity
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}



public abstract class DbEntityConfig<T> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<T>
    where T : class, IEntity
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<T> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(m => m.Id);
    }
}


public class ModelEntityConfig : DbEntityConfig<Model>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Model> builder)
    {
        base.Configure(builder);

        // Of course I want to avoid this call, cos TheOtherModel might not override base method
        // builder.ToTable("Models");

        builder.Property(m => m.Name).HasMaxLength(25);
    }
}
```

**Result**

```
public partial class Test : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Model",
            columns: table => new

            // code skipped for brevity
    }
}
```

**Expected result:**

```
public partial class Test : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Models",
            columns: table => new

            // code skipped for brevity
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The linked article is incorrect. As you can see from [Pluralization hook for DbContext Scaffolding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0) EF Core documentation:

> EF Core 2.0 introduces a new `IPluralizer` service that is used to singularize entity type names and pluralize `DbSet` names.

Shortly, it is used only by scaffolding commands, hence cannot be used for changing the table name model [conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/tables#conventions).

In general migration tools use the model the way it is configured by conventions, data annotations and fluent API. So applying custom convention should be with model API inside `OnModelCreating`. Something like this:

```
foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    entityType.Relational().TableName = GetTableName(entityType);
```

where `GetTableName` method implements your naming convention:

```
string GetTableName(IEntityType entityType)
{
    // use entiityType.Name and other info
    return ...; 
}
```

**Update (EF Core 3.0+):** Use `entityType.SetTableName(...)` in place of `entityType.Relational().TableName = ...`