# Singularise or pluralize table name entities

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am developing an application in .net core , used below command to create Entities

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=DBSERVER;Database=ExpenseManager;Trusted_Connection=false;
User ID=****;Password=*****;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

It created entities like below from database first approch,my table names are Expenses,Incomes,Users

```
 public virtual DbSet<Expenses> Expenses { get; set; }
 public virtual DbSet<Incomes> Incomes { get; set; }
 public virtual DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
```

But want to use singularise in object name like below

```
public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
```

I tried Nick N answer in [EntityFramework Core database first approach pluralizing table names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281647/entityframework-core-database-first-approach-pluralizing-table-names)

but it is not working.

Please help

Comment: Do you use Ef Core or EF 6?

Comment: @Nikolaus using Ef Core

Comment: Then you should use the right Tags for your question.

Comment: Did you try to install https://github.com/bricelam/EFCore.Pluralizer via nuget?

Comment: yes tried, still not working after recreating

Comment: What’s your error?

Comment: No error ,after running Scaffold-DbContext command entities created with same

Comment: Another option is to use [EfCorePowerTools](https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools), which gives you more control on [Reverse Engineering](https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools/wiki/Reverse-Engineering) process.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the Package `Bricelam.EntityFrameworkCore.Pluralizer` from Manage NuGet Packages or Package Manager Console and then run Scaffold-DbContext command. You could refer to [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11084#issuecomment-369998391) .