# Using Singular Table Names with EF Core 2

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I want my domain class name to match my db table name (no pluralisation).

In EF Core 1.1, I used this code to do that:

```
public static void RemovePluralisingTableNameConvention(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    foreach (IMutableEntityType entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        entityType.Relational().TableName = entityType.DisplayName();
    }
}
```

In EF Core 2.0, this code doesn't compile as `Relational()` is not a method on IMutableEntityType. 
Anyway, in EF Core 2.0, they have added IPluralizer, documented here:

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/blob/master/entity-framework/core/what-is-new/index.md#pluralization-hook-for-dbcontext-scaffolding

There aren't many examples to show how to achieve the same behaviour that I had before. Any clue of how to remove pluralisation in EF Core 2?

Comment: EF Core 2.0's convention is to use a DbSet's name for a table. If you never specified a DbSet for a table then EF Core will use the class name as the table name. Obviously this is all ignored if you specified the table name by using ToTable in the fluent mapping.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use exactly the same code. `Relational()` is *extension* method defined in the [`RelationalMetadataExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalmetadataextensions) class inside `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll` *assembly*, so make sure you are referencing it.

What about `IPluralizer`, as you can see from the link it's just a *Pluralization hook for DbContext Scaffolding*, i.e. entity class generation from database, *used to singularize entity type names and pluralize DbSet names*. It's not used for table name generation. The default table name convention is explained in [Table Mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/tables) section of the documentation:

> By convention, each entity will be setup to map to a table with the same name as the `DbSet<TEntity>` property that exposes the entity on the derived context. If no `DbSet<TEntity>` is included for the given entity, the class name is used.

Comment: Relational() is part of an internal namespace, and may not be available anymore in further versions.

Comment: @Matthieu Nope. If you follow the link, you'll see that it is part of the **public** API. That doesn't stop them to remove it in 3.0 as "breaking change" though :)

Comment: "If no DbSet<TEntity> is included for the given entity" - how would it even know to create the table in the first place?

Comment: @Tod Exposing `DbSet<TEntity>` property is optional (even though the most commonly used). There are other ways for [Including types in the model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-types?tabs=data-annotations#including-types-in-the-model)

Comment: By recursive discovery? I see they also have a Table attribute which negates the need for my comment in the answer above. 

Answer (score 16):

You can do it this way without using internal EF API calls by using the `ClrType.Name`

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        // Use the entity name instead of the Context.DbSet<T> name
        // refs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-types?tabs=fluent-api#table-name
        modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.ClrType).ToTable(entityType.ClrType.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  and for anyone looking for lowercase table names `.ToTable(entityType.ClrType.Name.ToLower())`

Comment: I used this but extended my models with a TableNameAttribute and decorated the model with that to generate the table name instead.

Answer (score 11):

In case anyone wants to try in .NET Core 3.1, you can build extension method as

```
public static class ModelBuilderExtension
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Remove pluralizing table name convention to create table name in singular form.
    /// </summary>       
    public static void RemovePluralizingTableNameConvention(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        foreach (IMutableEntityType entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            entityType.SetTableName(entityType.DisplayName());
        }
    }
}
```

Ensure you install the dependent package: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational`

Comment: I was having  issues with this approach as value objects were treated as entities after setting table name against them (at least in EF Core 5). Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

This is the extension of @Vicram answer.
I applied it in EF Core 5

```
modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()            
    .Configure(e => e.SetTableName(e.DisplayName()));
```

but then if you have value objects in your domain they will all be treated as entity types and created as tables in the database. If your value objects all inherit from a base type like `ValueObject` you can use the following:

```
modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()            
    .Where(x => !x.ClrType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ValueObject)))
    .Configure(e => e.SetTableName(e.DisplayName()));
```

I have not checked other EF core versions but surely it is the case in version 5.

Another drawback in EF Core 5 is that when you use inheritance in your entity model, setting tables names changes from [Table-per-Hierarchy](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-hierarchy-and-discriminator-configuration) (TPH) to [Table-per-Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-type-configuration) (TPT)

You could use the following alternative (assuming your entities derive from `BaseEntity` class)

```
modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
    .Where(x => x.ClrType.BaseType == typeof(BaseEntity))
    .Configure(e => e.SetTableName(e.DisplayName()));
```

Where `Configure` extension is

```
public static class ModelBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void Configure(this IEnumerable<IMutableEntityType> entityTypes, Action<IMutableEntityType> convention)
    {
        foreach (var entityType in entityTypes)
        {
            convention(entityType);
        }
    }

    public static void Configure(this IEnumerable<IMutableProperty> propertyTypes, Action<IMutableProperty> convention)
    {
        foreach (var propertyType in propertyTypes)
        {
            convention(propertyType);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The best answer.

Comment: Where do you get the .Configure from in EF 6?

Answer (score 0):

In EF Core 2 you can add a [hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#pluralization-hook-for-dbcontext-scaffolding). What is mind bending is that if you use this to generate classes in a library project that has the entities for an asp.net core app, you need to go to package manager console select your library project as default project and add those hooks in the mvc web project. If you add the hooks in the library one it doesn't discover the hook.

You can test it works with

```
public void ConfigureDesignTimeServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    throw new Exception("works");
    services.AddSingleton<IPluralizer, MyPluralizer>();
}
```