# How to "re-pluralize" database tables after moving from .NET 4.5 to .NET Core 2.2?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have a project that I'm moving from .NET 4.5 to .NET Core, for some reason (that I can't remember), I wanted to prevent pluralization of the table names when I ran an `update-database` like so (.NET 4.5):

```
public class UncoveredLink : DbContext
{
    //removed constructor for brevity

    public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Artist> Artists { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //the line I'm talking about is here
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }

}
```

So, when I look at my database in SQL Management Studio I see the following:

```
//what I see
dbo.Album
dbo.Artist

//what i want
dbo.Albums
dbo.Artists
```

I believe the lack of pluralization is what is causing this error when I try and load a page:

```
SqlException: Invalid object name 'Albums'.

//further down the stack trace i see
UnLink.Services.AlbumService.GetAlbumByStringExt(string stringExt) in AlbumService.cs
album = _db.Albums.Where(x => x.StringExt == stringExt).FirstOrDefault();
```

See? I'm trying to call `_db.Albums` but I believe I can't do this because the table is not pluralized and my Core Context doesn't have a pluralization `OnModelCreating` like my .NET 4.5 did (can't seem to add it).

My new DbContext in .NET Core 2.2 looks like this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{

    public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Artist> Artists { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

}
```

How can I update the table names? The tables in my Core DbContext (as seen above) are already pluralized so I can't make a change to the DbContext that would be tracked for a new `add-migration`... do I just manually create a migration file and update the table names like:

`migrationBuilder.RenameTable(name: "Artist", schema: "dbo", newName: "Artists", newSchema: "dbo");`

I thought it wasn't good practice to create a migration for something that wasn't actually changed/tracked in the code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46498420/1663001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be helpful:

```
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
    {
          modelBuilder.Entity<Album>()
                        .ToTable("Album");
    }
```

another way is:

```
[Table("Album")]
 public class Album
    {
        public int AlbumId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Interesting! So this the equivalent to what I have in my .NET 4.5 Context?

Comment: Im not sure but maybe this attribute can work `[Table("Albums")]`

Comment: I had to change the `.ToTable("Albums")` to `.ToTable("Album")` to get it to work, so once you change that, I'll mark as correct

Comment: @ Jordan Lewallen thanks for your tip I changed it.

Comment: It’s Table(“Album”) as well on second example!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have made a change in the code, because you used to have that line about `Remove<Pluralizing>`, but now you don't. Unfortunately, `Add-Migration` might not pick up this change, especially when you're converting to .Net Core at the same time.

Since your model doesn't match your tables, you have the following options:

1. Manually create a migration that changes the table names:

`migrationBuilder.RenameTable("Album", newName: "Albums");`

OR
2. Write a query directly to the Db in SQL to change the table names:

`EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.Album', 'dbo.Albums';`

Comment: Thanks, okay so I had to remove that line because `PluralizingTableNameConvention` did not exist in Core. Looks like the fix will be easier than I thought, will give this a shot

Comment: Renaming the tables is extreme and will break anything else that accesses them. Just fix the model.

Comment: @DavidG, I would agree, except the OP stated he wanted them to be plural in the db, and it seems like a small enough project that it is likely everything is going through EF anyways.

Comment: @DavidG In terms of just fixing the model, you would suggest what hassan mentioned in his answer about adding a data annotation above `Album` to explicitly state its pluralized name?

Answer (score 0):

EF Core 2.0 introduces a new IPluralizer service that is used to singularize entity type names and pluralize DbSet names.

Maybe you could look into that. Plenty of posts about this on here or [here's](http://anthonygiretti.com/2018/01/12/entity-framework-core-2-pluralization-and-singularization/) a blog post about that