# 2 Foreign Keys as Primary Key using EF Core 2.0 Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two tables: **Comment** and **Like**.

```
public class Comment {
  CommentID { get; set; }
  ....
}

public class Like {
  CommentID { get; set; }
  UserID { get; set; }
}
```

Using entity framework core 2.0 code first, I want to define my "Like" model as only having the two fields which reference other primary keys (as foreign keys) but also I want the combination of the values to be the Primary Key of the table.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: See [Keys (primary)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys), specifically the part starting with *"You can also use the Fluent API to configure multiple properties to be the key of an entity (known as a composite key)"*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, here's what's going on here:

1) There are two classes: `Comment` and `User`.

2) The third class, `Like`, holds references (navigation properties) to both two those classes which correspond to foreign keys in database: `UserId` and `CommentId`. I explicitly used `ForeignKey` attribute, so that it would be clear to you which properties EF will use as foreign keys. In this particular case you could omit this attribute since EF will figure it out automatically (since names match in both classes). Note that it's not mandatory to have foreign keys, but they have advantages.

3) The `UserId` and `CommentId` comprise composite key. The `Column` attribute configures the order of columns in database (so called ordinals). This is important for EF.

4) The `User` and `Comment` classes also have navigation properties (since it's `one` side of `one-to-many` relations): `Likes`.

5) Finally, `always` use `Table` attribute to avoid problems with pluralizations because [there's no way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37493095/entity-framework-core-rc2-table-name-pluralization) to turn it off.

```
[Table("Comment")]
public class Comment
{
    public int CommentID { get; set; }
    public List<Like> Likes { get; set; }
}

[Table("User")]
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public List<Like> Likes { get; set; }
}

[Table("Like")]
public class Like
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int CommentID { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CommentId")]
    public Comment Comment { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE**

**Setting composite key in EF Core**

The `Key` (and `Column`) attributes, used to designate composite primary key, actually, don't work in EF Core - they work in EF6. To configure composite key in EF Core, you need to use Fluent Configuration.

You have two options to do it.

**OPTION 1.** Make all the configuration in `OnModelCreatingMethod`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Like>().HasKey(l => new { l.CommentID, l.UserID });
}
```

**OPTION 2.** Move all the configuration into separate class and apply it in `OnModelCreating`:

1) Create separate class for configuration

```
class LikeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Like>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Like> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(l => new { l.CommentID, l.UserID });
    }
}
```

2) Apply configuration:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new LikeConfiguration());
}
```

Choose any option you like.

As you see, to configure composite key in Fluent Configuration, you need to use [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types). And again, the order of properties matters.

Comment: could you please help answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56584027/entity-framework-insert-conflicts-with-another-foreign-key