# EF Core APIs removed, now how to remove automatic pluralization?

Tags: entity-framework-core

(This is not a dupe, please read my comment.)

I've just migrated from EF Core Preview 5  to Preview 6.
This seems to be a breaking change, especially the mapping will break to the existing Databases if this remains in the release version.

In preview 5 I used:

```
entityType.Relational.TableName = entityType.DisplayName();
```

Now it seems `Relational` property was removed. I would not fall back to manually declare the TableName for all dozens of entities, instead just instruct EF Core model builder do not pluralize automatically them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Core RC2 table name pluralization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37493095/entity-framework-core-rc2-table-name-pluralization)

Comment: Thx, I reviewed that Q. There almost all answers mention "entity.Relational().TableName =...."  as solution. My question is about this API removed and no longer available

Comment: The API is removed. > "There is no convention for this as of EF RC2 build"

Comment: Is it DisplayName you are missing?

Comment: @JanPaoloGo: That API was not removed. Please consider my issue started few days ago with Core 3 preview6 that answer is more than 3 years old. The API I an looking for is existed few days ago.

Comment: Oh, you're talking about `entityType.Relational.TableName = entityType.DisplayName();`. I was talking about the `PluralizingTableNameConvention`. my bad

Comment: @ErikEJ: No the .Relational property is missing, (I am going to edit the Q)

Comment: @JanPaoloGo how can you possibly mark duplicate on a preview 6 question with a 3 year old answer

Comment: @AvinKavish: To be fair, my question was not so clear in its original form... now it evolved a bit

Comment: Using preview (beta) versions is on your own risk. They are expected to have breaking changes or non working things. To me it doesn't worth the effort to search the code base which can be changed at any moment before release.

Comment: @IvanStoev, hopefully we all know that beta versions expected to have breaking changes. I was not complaining. What worth and what not, could be different by person, project, context. Btw my guess this change will remain a breaking in the release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[EF Core 3 introduces, starting preview6, breaking changes on Provider-specific Metadata API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#provider-specific-metadata-api-changes). This includes removal of `RelationalMetadataExtensions` together with its extension methods such as `Relational(this IMutableEntityType entityType)`.

It is replaced by [`RelationalEntityTypeExtensions`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/master/src/EFCore.Relational/Extensions/RelationalEntityTypeExtensions.cs) where you can do the following:

```cs
IMutableEntityType entity = ...;
entity.SetTableName(entity.DisplayName());
```

With that, removing automatic pluralization can be done as described in [this answer on a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37502978/5588197)

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

public static class ModelBuilderExtensions 
{
    public static void RemovePluralizingTableNameConvention(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        foreach (IMutableEntityType entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            entity.SetTableName(entity.DisplayName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This SetTableName overwrites the [Table("MyTableName")] attribute, back to DisplayName. Is there any way to make this just default (if there is no [Table...] attribute? With other words make the default behaviour no pluralizing, but allow to use [Table...] attribute?

Comment: @g.pickardou you could use reflection e.g. `entity.ClrType.GetCustomAttribute<TableAttribute>()?.Name != null` to check if the type has `[Table...]` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Improved version of [Jan Paolo Go's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56689384/1361096) This prevents intermediate table to become something like ***TeacherStudent Dictionary<string, object>***

```
public static class ModelBuilderExtensions 
{
    public static void RemovePluralizingTableNameConvention(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    
        foreach (IMutableEntityType entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
           if (entity is EntityType { IsImplicitlyCreatedJoinEntityType: true })
           {
             continue;
           }
           entity.SetTableName(entity.DisplayName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The 'entity is EntityType' check should be inside the foreach loop.