# C#, EF6, SQLite and table naming

Tags: entity-framework

In order to setup a connection to a (SQLite) db, in NET6-7-8 (EF Core) I would do the following:

**DB**

```
+----------------------+
| Articoli             |
+----+-----------------+
| PK | IDArticolo      |
|    | Field2          |
|    | Field3          |
+----+-----------------+
```

*(Please note: "Articolo" is the Italian for "Item", and its plural is "Articoli", this will become relevant later on)*

**MyDbContext.cs**

```
internal class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    /* ... */

    public DbSet<Articolo> Articoli { get; set; }
}
```

**Articolo.cs**

```
internal class Articolo
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int IDArticolo { get; set; }

    /* ... some other properties ... */
}
```

So I have a table in the DB called `Articoli` (*Items*), a class in my code named `Articolo` (*Item*) and a `DbSet<Articolo> Articoli` that should map to my `Articoli` table.

Given all this, I should be able to query my db this way:

```
using (var dc = new MyDbContext())
{
    var q = dc.Articoli.ToList();
}
```

IntelliSense tells me that `dc` has an `Articoli` property and code compiles and runs.

This works perfectly in a NET8 project.

If I transpose the very same code in a NET Framework 4.8/EF6 project, IntelliSense tells me again that `dc` has an `Articoli` property, code compiles, but when I actually execute `var q = dc.Articoli.ToList();` it throws the following exception:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: 'An error
> occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner
> exception for details.'
>
> Inner Exception: SQLiteException: SQL logic error no such table:
> Articoloes

It seems that EF6 is trying to convert `Articolo` to plural using English rules and use that as a table name instead of the one I provide when defining the DbSet.

I solved this by adding a `Table` attribute to my class:

```
[Table("Articoli")]
internal class Articolo
{ /* ... */ }
```

but I wonder why is this happening and if there is a way to tell EF6 to stop trying to guess table names.

**UPDATE 1**

Based on @phuzi suggestion, I tried to add this to my DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}
```

Unfortunately this only changes the exception to:

> Inner Exception: SQLiteException: SQL logic error no such table: Articolo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How turn off pluralize table creation for Entity Framework 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130059/how-turn-off-pluralize-table-creation-for-entity-framework-5) Applies equally to EF6.

Comment: Thank you @phuzi Unfortunately it does not work. I updated question with details.

Comment: It did stop trying to use the (English) pluralisation the error uses the class name `Articolo` not `Articoloes` as it was previously. It appears that it's also ignoring the name in the `TableAttribute` , or did you remove that as well?